# What is the grammar behind 'te' 'soshite' and 'to'?

Tags: grammar, て-form, conjunctions

I want to know which 'and' to use in this context:

I went out today and it was fun.

I don't know for sure if it is 'te'.

Comment: Not sure the linked answer would answer the question completely, if the question is also trying to clarify the usage of "と/to" such as トンネルを抜ける/と/そこは雪国だった。or 学校に行く/と/楽しい as the linked page looks only talks about と to link nouns.